# Как создать несколько переменных в цкле python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Собственно вопрос:

```py
i = 0
for item in items:
    Dict_<вот сюда i> = item
    i = i + 1
```

В общем чтобы на выходе создались переменные Dict_0, Dict_1 и т.д.

Каждый item представляет собой строку формата "status: text\n parametr: text\n out: text". Нужно загнать каждую строку в свою переменную, чтобы потом преобразовать её в словарь

Comment: Каждый item представляет собой строку формата "status: text\n parametr: text\n out: text". Нужно загнать каждую строку в свою переменную, чтобы потом преобразовать её в словарь.

Comment: и меняется только text, а ключи status,parametr,out - одинаковые, правильно?

Comment: Да ключи не меняются. Только текст

Comment: Зачем вам отдельные переменные, используйте сразу словарь: `d = dict()` и потом `d[i] = item`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас в `items` список строк такого вида:

```
items = [
    'status: text01\n parametr: text02\n out: text03',
    'status: text04\n parametr: text05\n out: text06',
    'status: text07\n parametr: text08\n out: text09',
    'status: text10\n parametr: text11\n out: text12',
    'status: text13\n parametr: text14\n out: text15'
]
```

то можно делить каждый элемент по переносу и двоеточию:

```
result = [dict(x.split(": ") for x in i.split("\n ")) for i in items]
```

в `result` - список словарей:

```
[
    {'status': 'text01', 'parametr': 'text02', 'out': 'text03'}, 
    {'status': 'text04', 'parametr': 'text05', 'out': 'text06'}, 
    {'status': 'text07', 'parametr': 'text08', 'out': 'text09'}, 
    {'status': 'text10', 'parametr': 'text11', 'out': 'text12'}, 
    {'status': 'text13', 'parametr': 'text14', 'out': 'text15'}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
for item in items:
    locals()[f'Dict_<вот сюда {i}>'] = item
    i = i + 1
```

Ваши переменные в виде f'Dict_<вот сюда {i}>'